# Aligning <li's> next to eachother in full width dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

So I'm having a bit of a problem. I've created a fullwidth dropdown menu that contains a few `li's` with menu-items in them. I made it fullwidth with the `padding: 0 1000em; margin: 0 -1000em;` trick but now the `li's` are being placed under each other.

The goal is to place the li's next to each other and I'm getting stuck here. Any solutions? Below is the code being used.

To make it a bit clear I've made a image to show what I mean. The first one is how it displays now and the second one is how I'd like it to be displayed: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcfVr.jpg

HTML:

```
<nav class="main-navigation clearfix">
            <ul id="menu">
               <li class="hovertest">   
                   <a href="category.html">Men</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="subcategory.html">Shoes</a>
                                <ul class="subsubmenu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="subsubcategory.html">Slippers</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And the CSS:

```
.header-container .navigation-container {width: 100%; padding: 0; margin:0 auto; clear: both; }
.header-container .main-navigation {}

.header-container .main-navigation ul{float: left;  margin: 3px 0 0 0; padding:0; list-style-type:none}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li{float:left; margin: 0; font-family: 'NewCenturySchlbkLTPro-Roman', Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 12px; position:relative; }
.header-container .main-navigation ul li a{letter-spacing: .2em; color: #000; display: block; padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; outline-style: none;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li a:hover,
.header-container .main-navigation ul li.active a{color: #7b4a59; box-shadow: 0 14px 0px 0px white, 135px -8px 0px 0px white, 1px 0 9px 0px #cccccc, -2px 0 6px -3px #cccccc}

.header-container .main-navigation ul.submenu{margin:0;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu{position:absolute; width:250px; padding-top:15px; }
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu li{display:none; position: relative; left: 0; top: 100%; padding: 0 1000em; margin: 0 -1000em; z-index: 101;     -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}

.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu li a{letter-spacing: .2em; color: #000; display: block; padding: 0; outline-style: none;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu li a:hover,
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu li.active a{color: #7b4a59;}

.header-container .main-navigation ul li:hover ul.submenu li{display:block; z-index:999; background-color:white; float:none; overflow:auto; padding-bottom:25px;}

.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.subsubmenu li{box-shadow:none;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.subsubmenu li a{color:red;}
```

Comment: With `float` you need to specify a `width`. If you don't care about the `width` being the same, just use `display: inline;`. Also post actual HTML, not bound data, we can't know what the output is

Comment: Hmm for some reason when I try that all the items are placed all over the place. The bound data is just some links, nothing fancy and not that important.

Comment: you say, "when I try that". specifying width, or inline? Also post actual HTML please

Comment: Sorry, meant the inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is still looking for something like this, it's like this:

```
/*Main menu*/
.header-container .navigation-container {width: 100%; padding: 0; margin:0 auto; clear: both; }
.header-container .main-navigation {}

.header-container .main-navigation ul{float: left; padding:0; list-style-type:none; margin:0;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li{float:left; margin: 0; margin-left:-10px; margin-right:10px; font-family: 'NewCenturySchlbkLTPro-Roman', Georgia, Times New Roman, serif; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 12px; position:relative; }
.header-container .main-navigation ul li a{letter-spacing: .2em; color: #000; display: block; padding: 16px 10px 15px 10px; outline-style: none;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li a:hover{color: #7b4a59; }
.header-container .main-navigation ul li.menu-list:hover > ul{visibility: visible; opacity: 1; border-top:1px solid #cccccc;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li.menu-list:hover:after{content:""; position:relative; display:block; width:100%; height:1px; background: #FFF; z-index:1000;}

.header-container .main-navigation ul li.menu-list{border-left:1px solid transparent ;border-top:1px solid transparent;border-right:1px solid transparent}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li.menu-list:hover,
.header-container .main-navigation ul li.menu-list.active a{color: #7b4a59; border-left:1px solid #cccccc;border-top:1px solid #cccccc;border-right:1px solid #cccccc}

/*Sub menu*/
.featured-menu{background-color:#e3e2e5;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul.submenu{margin:0;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu{position: absolute; left: 0;  padding-left: 100em; padding-right: 100em; margin: 0px -1034em 0 -100em; z-index: 101;
    visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; background: #ffffff;)
    -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);;
}

.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu li{display:none; position: relative; left: 0; top: 100%; z-index: 101;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu li:last-child{}

.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu li a{padding-top:15px; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:12px; letter-spacing: .2em; color: #000; display: block;  outline-style: none; }
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu li a:hover,
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.submenu li.active a{color: #7b4a59; box-shadow:none!important}

.header-container .main-navigation ul li:hover ul.submenu li{display: block; z-index:999; background-color:transparent; float:left; padding:25px 15px 25px 10px; overflow:auto;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li:hover ul.submenu li:first-child{}

/*Sub sub menu*/
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.subsubmenu li{box-shadow:none!important; float:none!important; padding-bottom:0!important; padding-top:0!important; padding-left:0!important;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.subsubmenu li a{margin-left:5px; font-family: 'Swiss721BT-Light',"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: .1em; color: #000; padding-bottom:0px;}
.header-container .main-navigation ul li ul.subsubmenu li a:last-child{padding-bottom:15px; padding-top:0px; margin-left:15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the **ul** display as inline-block

```css
ul.menu {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
ul.menu li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div id='menucontainer'>
  <ul id='menu1' class='menu'>
    <li>One-1</li>
    <li>One-2</li>
    <li>One-3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id='menu2' class='menu'>
    <li>Two-1</li>
    <li>Two-2</li>
    <li>Two-3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```